# python Ai, can you make lists inside lists that you can access form the outer list?

Tags: python, list, tuples, artificial-intelligence

I am making an AI, i want for my AI (Jarvis) to know all the different ways to say something. I wish to make like a synonym bank, but i want to have a list or a tuple or something that have all the lists of synonyms in them, or at least a bunch of phases that are interchangeable in a sentence. Would this be correct down bellow?

```
synonym_bank = [("what's","what is"),("where is","where's")]
```

I want it to know that the phrases in the same lists mean the same things, and could be used coherently in the sentence as a replacement of the word used originally. I want to then be able to be able to use something that looks to see if any words in the sentence the AI receives is in any of those lists to see if there are any synonyms, for example:

```
Jarvis where are we right now
```

jarvis would see jarvis and would skip that and go to "where". i want jarvis to be able to ask me what i meant by using the synonyms, for example.

```
where are we currently?
```

jarvis might respond like this, and i would say yes and he would know that 
that currently is indeed a synonym of right now.

Comment: What is your actual question here? If it's "is a list of tuples a valid data structure", then the answer is "sure it is, though it may be slow for what you want to do". If it's "how do I make my magical not-yet-written AI understand synonyms, that's probably too broad a question for Stack Overflow. If you have an AI that understand one form of a word and are trying to add synonym recognition to that, show some more relevant code and ask a specific question about it and we might be able to help. But we're not going to write your AI for you.

Comment: yes of course!  Thank you

Comment: but my question is how can i write something that looks for if any of it's words are in one of those lists of synonyms!

Comment: You need to clearly state your question then. It's not at all obvious what behavior you want out of your "synonym bank". I'm guessing you want to be able to lookup one word and find all its synonyms, a task for which a normal dictionary seems perfectly adequate (with a loop and some slicing to fill it with the values from your list of tuples). But maybe you want something else, you haven't said. We don't need to know what your AI is going to say (since asking us to make it say that is too broad of question for this site). We do need to know what you're actually asking about.

Answer (score 0):

I had implemented an algorithm similar to your need in the past and [this paper](http://ants.iis.sinica.edu.tw/3BkMJ9lTeWXTSrrvNoKNFDxRm3zFwRR/55/Sentence%20Similarity%20Based%20on%20Semantic%20Nets%20and%20corpus%20statistics.pdf) helped me greatly in moving in right direction.

This will need some understanding of Natural Language Processing(NLP).

What you can do is to find similarities between two complete sentences using **Wordnet** corpus and proceed from there.

Note that this is one of the suggestion from many possible way to approach this problem.